# Hibernate : one to many mapping for multiple entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Suppose we have four entities A, B, C, and Document.

```
A -> Many Documents (one-to-many)
B -> Many Documents (one-to-many)
C -> Many Documents (one-to-many)
```

A, B, C can have many documents.
In traditional one-to-many mapping style we'll have Document table like below:

### Document Table:

### |doc_id | doc_field_1 | doc_field_2 | A_id | B_id | C_id |

if I add A entity's documents then, for these documants B_id and C_id would be  null.
same for B's and C's document.
hope problem is clear.

I want Document entity to keep only one id and entity class where I can query Document table in hibernate way.

Or any other way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thorben Jansssen wrote a great blog post on this.

https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/

For your case, Single table strategy may be appropriate. If you don't want a_id, b_id, c_id would be null, you may replace them with just 2 columns:

|doc_id | doc_field_1 | doc_field_2 | type | entity_id|

and Entity mapping as follow:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
@Table(name = "document")
public abstract class Document {
    // ...
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "A")
public class DocumentOfTypeA extends Document{
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @Column(name="entity_id")
    A aEntity;
}
```

and your entity class:

```
// A.java
public class A{
    // ...
    // @OneToMany (...)
    private Set<DocumentOfTypeA> documents;
}
```

Same to B and C entities.

Answer (score 0):

Note that each of the objects A,B,C also have an ID field in their tables. In most cases, these are all generated by the database using a sequence generator:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seqA", sequenceName = "seqA_gen")

@Entity
public class A {


  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqA")
  @Id
  private Long Id

  @OneToMany (...)
  private Set<Document> documents;

}
```

The Id values for Class A could be the same as Class B or C.  If you use a single table to store the Document rows for all of the three classes, in the normal circumstance, you have to use some other property beyond the Id to figure out which rows belong to an object.  This is done either with multiple ID columns as you have shown, or a single Id column and a discriminator column which essentially says "this ID is for class A"

So here's another approach:  **Use only one Id sequence generator for all three classes.**

This can be done by simply using the same sequenceName for all three classes.

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seqA", sequenceName = "shared_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seqB", sequenceName = "shared_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seqC", sequenceName = "shared_gen")
```

If you use the same sequence generator, Ids never overlap and you can use a single column in the document table to link @onetomany for all parent classes. There is never a case where a query by Id returns data for a different parent.

A second approach that may be more common is to **use random UUIDs** as the Id generator for classes A,B and C.  The Ids take additional memory but provide statistically complete isolation.

These two approaches make it possible for any number of new classes can be added to the application that include a set of Documents without modifying the columns in the Documents table or requiring the developer to keep track of discrimination values.